# Microsoft Moles and type casting

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moles

I tries some Unit Testing and ran into a problem of testing methods which use classes instances and not the interfaces. In that case I found that MS Moles can help me. But the it seems that they are not friendly with type casting situations. And I found no info and even no questions how to deal with this situation. Example:

```
public class ClassA
{
 public int Number {get {return 10;}}
}

public class ClassB
{
 public int Count1(ClassA arg) { return arg.Number; } 
 public int Count2(object arg) { return (arg as ClassA).Number; }
}
```

and while testing

```
var cl = new MolesUnitTesting.Moles.MClassA();
MolesUnitTesting.Moles.MClassA.AllInstances.NumberGet = t1 => 20;
```

The first `Count` works just fine and returns 20 but casting in the second returns `Null`. Is there any way to test such method without using interface and usual mocking? If there is other lib that can help me please provide me with it's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mocking all instances of the `ClassA` type you can do the following:

```
var target = new MClassA();

target.NumberGet = () => 42;

Assert.AreEqual(Count1(target), 42);
Assert.AreEqual(Count2(target.Instance), 42);
```

Notice that for the `Count1` you can use the mole directly because it will be automatically converted to a `ClassA` instance. However, since `Count2` receives an `object` you need to be explicit and passed the `target.Instance` which represents the moled `ClassA` instance.

The reason `Count1(target)` works is because the generated mole class `MClassA`, which inherits from `MoleBase<ClassA>`, defines the following implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator ClassA(MoleBase<ClassA> mole) { // ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. Previously I also tried to use Instance from the moled class but it returned me the original value, but now all is fine. Seems like magic to me.